# Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type AuthResult?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to code user authentication system.But everytime I get this error, "only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type AuthResult?"

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener{

     if(!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

     Log.d("Main","Successfully created user with uid: ${it.result.user.uid}")
}
```

Comment: It just says that `it.result` can be nullable therefore if you want access to its properties you have to either use `?.` null safe or `!!.` null asserted getters. This warning comes from Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

William's answer is close, but not exactly 100% accurate.

[createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) returns a Task.  [Task.getResult()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getResult()) is actually annotated as returning `@Nullable` in Java like this:

```
@Nullable
public abstract TResult getResult();
```

Ignoring for a moment whether it actually makes sense for it to be defined like this, what this definition is telling Kotlin is that the return value of `getResult()` needs to be checked for null before it can be safely used.  Therefore, you'll need to guard check the result in some way before calling its methods.  Here's one way that checks explicitly:

```
val result = it.result  // Kotlin says result is of type "AuthResult?"
if (result != null) {
    val user = result.user   // Kotlin says user is of type "FirebaseUser?"
    if (user != null) {
        Log.d("Main", "Successfully created user with uid: ${user.uid}")
    }
}
```

Not also that you have to check `result.getUser()` for null as well, since it's also defined `@Nullable`.  Be sure to check in your IDE the types and definitions of things so you can better understand their nullability guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that `AuthResult?` is a nullable type (returned from `it.result` / `it.getResult()`) which is a fundamental concept of Kotlin. That means that the compiler can't guarentee that the resulting `AuthResult` is null or not, so it is telling you, that you must check yourself.

Using the `!!` you are saying, "I know this won't be null, just force it into a non-nullable type". This may bring upon a `NullPointerException`.

Using the `?.` operator, you are saying, if `AuthResult` is not null, perform this operation

Comment: `AuthResult` is **not** a nullable type; `AuthResult?` is.

Comment: `AuthResult` is not a nullable type.  The problem here is that `getResult()` is annotated `@Nullable`, which means that Kotlin will produce an `AuthResult?` type result.  See my answer for full details.